# Fill a div with Items using float left and a left margin

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a div of 960px that i want to fill with five items using a float left. Currently I am separating each item with a 10px right margin but this leaves me with a 10px space at the right of my container div.

My question is how can I fill the div completely without having this space on the right of the container div?

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks for your help

BC

Answer (score 3):

Use margin left and first-child pseudo selector

```
   #wrapper #div:first-child{margin-left:0}
```

Comment: last-child is not supported in IE 6,7,8

Comment: forgot, you can use left margin and first-child though

Answer (score 1):

do no use margin for last item

```
.lastItem
{
  margin-right: 0;
}
```